# How to add an animation in SceneKit on request

Tags: swift, animation, scenekit

If you can help me add this animation to the scene or if you know how to add an animation to the scene, it would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
let BallScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Ball.dae")!
let ManScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Genric_Simplifiyed9.dae")!
let Man: SCNNode = ManScene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Bob_001", recursively: true)!
Man.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
BallScene.rootNode.addChildNode(Man)

let Animation: CAAnimation
let AnimationUrl: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("art.scnassets/Genric_Simplifiyed9.dae", withExtension: "dae")!
let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(URL: AnimationUrl, options: [SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyKey : SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyDoNotPlay])

sceneSource.addAnimation(attackAnimation, forKey: "attack”)
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code? What do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: there is a error because "attackAmination" does not exist so it doesn't run. But the point is that i don't know how to set up the the line of code so that the "attackAnimation" actual pulls the animation from the .dae file and uses it. Is there a simple way to just pull and run an  animation on the guy from the .dae file because the amination that i made in blender is attached to the .dae file. like if the Man was the main scene instead of the ball then the animation from the man would automatically play but because the Man is a Child node of the ball it doesn't play at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a DAE/COLLADA file with animations and you can just click play button  to play the animation in your storyboard.
Then you can just

```
let subScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/test_ball_2011.dae")!
let childNodes = subScene.rootNode.childNodes
for child in childNodes {
    //child.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -100)
    rootScene.rootNode.addChildNode(child)
}
```

The animation will play in your rootScene

and you can use

```
for child in childNodes {
   let keys = child.animationKeys
   child.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -100)
   for key in keys {
       let animation = child.animationForKey(key)!
       animation.repeatCount = 5
       child.removeAnimationForKey(key) 
       child.addAnimation(animation, forKey: key)
   }
   rootScene.rootNode.addChildNode(child)
```

to set the position or the repeatCount...

Another way like your code:
you can use

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(/* your DAE file */)
let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(URL: url, options: [
        SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyKey : SCNSceneSourceAnimationImportPolicyPlayRepeatedly
])!
```

to get the source and in the options you can set many things, just check API
and use

```
let node = sceneSource.entryWithIdentifier("/* the node name */", withClass: SCNNode.self)
let animation = sceneSource.entryWithIdentifier("/* the animation name */", withClass: CAAnimation.self)
```

to get the node and the animation. If the two files is in different file, just make 2 sources to get :)
the last thing is `node.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)` // check the API

Comment: I have for sure an animation with a specific key inside the .scn file, but entryWithIdentifier return always nil. Why?